# Present and layout a set of buttons in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, architecture, razor

I am working on a computer support incident management system.

Currently, a `Review` view  for an incident contains several incident manipulation buttons, that are "rendered" onto the view with the help of the following logic:

A model for the view contains several methods that can tell if some action is allowed to be currently executed on this incident

`A part ViewModel to which the Review view is bound:`

```
    ...

    public bool CanContactUser()
    {
        return _manager.CanContactUser(Incident, User);
    }

    public bool CanComment()
    {
        return _manager.CanSetComment(Incident);
    }

    ...
```

In the view, depending on the result of these methods, the actual button for particular action is either displayed or not:

```
...

@if (Model.CanContactUser())
{
    @Html.MakePopupForm("ContactUser", new[] { "id" }, title: "Register user contact", refreshOnSuccess: true, okText: "Save", cancelText: "Cancel", resizable: false)
}

@if (Model.CanComment())
{
    @Html.MakePopupForm("Comment", new[] { "id" }, title: "Comment", refreshOnSuccess: true, okText: "Save", cancelText: "Cancel", resizable: false)
}

...
```

I feel that it is a bad practice. Even though it works, I am willing to have a collection of  available buttons in memory (in C# code), I guess in a ViewModel class instance, and bind the view to render this collection.

How can this be achieved? Binding the view to a collection of buttons in particular. I can generate an abstract collection of `List<AvailableButton> buttonsToRenderAsHtml` ...But how do I link Razor to display it in a controlled fashion?

Comment: you can check if that form can render in your helper. Just send an enum value and check is that view can render your partial view

Comment: There has to be something in my partial view that let's it know how to render a List<AvailaleActionButton>. The question is what? It should be pretty simple from what I can imagine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this depends on your preference.

If you have a contiguous set of buttons in your layout then you could add your property to your existing view model and then render in a loop.  EG:

```
@foreach(var button in Model.AvailableButtons) {
   YourButtonRenderMethod(button)
}
```

or have a shared partial view that can render a set of buttons with:

`@model IEnumerable<AvailableButton>`.

In that case you can just call:

`@Html.RenderPartial("SetOfButtons", Model.AvailableButtons)`

This is how I tend to build out my UI using composable partial views

But if your buttons are scattered in different areas of your view layout then I don't think you have a choice but to check individually.

It is strictly view logic, so you shouldn't feel bad about that in my opinion.